# Creating a function for several SQL DB tables to summarize missingness and null values

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I am trying to create a function in R using the RODBC package to loop through five tables in a SQL database to find the count of rows for each year for each variable, the % null for each year for each var, and the % missing for each year for each var.  I am having trouble creating a single function to give me this output. I have managed to find a function that counts total, missing and null, then I add 2 vars post-facto that create percentages (first code set). Then I also created a function that outputs the total count and percent null, but cannot seem to get it to produce an accurate percent missing directly (second code set).  Any help with this would be much appreciated.

First code set:

```
test1 <- sqlQuery(channel, "select 
              [EVENT_YEAR] AS 'YEAR', 
              COUNT(*) AS 'TOTAL',
              SUM(CASE WHEN MOTHER_EDUCATION_TRENDABLE IS NULL THEN 1   ELSE 0 END) AS 'NULL_VAL',
              SUM(CASE WHEN MOTHER_EDUCATION_TRENDABLE = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'MISS_VAL'

              from [GA_CMH].[dbo].[BIRTHS]

              GROUP BY [EVENT_YEAR]
              ORDER BY [EVENT_YEAR]")

test1$nullpct<-with(test1, NULL_VAL/TOTAL)
test1$misspct<-with(test1, MISS_VAL/TOTAL)
```

Second code set:

```
PctNull <- sqlQuery(channel, "select 
                [EVENT_YEAR] AS 'YEAR', 
                COUNT(*) AS 'TOTAL',
                (((COUNT(*) - COUNT(MOTHER_EDUCATION_TRENDABLE))*100)/COUNT(*)) AS 'PctNull'


                from [GA_CMH].[dbo].[BIRTHS]

                GROUP BY [EVENT_YEAR]
                ORDER BY [EVENT_YEAR]")
```

Attempt to merge the two:

```
PctNull <- sqlQuery(channel, "select 
                [EVENT_YEAR] AS 'YEAR', 
                COUNT(*) AS 'TOTAL',
                (((COUNT(CASE WHEN MOTHER_EDUCATION_TRENDABLE = -1 THEN 1 END)) /(COUNT(*)))*100) AS 'PctMiss',
                (((COUNT(*) - COUNT(MOTHER_EDUCATION_TRENDABLE))*100)/COUNT(*)) AS 'PctNull'


                from [GA_CMH].[dbo].[BIRTHS]

                GROUP BY [EVENT_YEAR]
                ORDER BY [EVENT_YEAR]")
```

This last code returns inaccurate percentages for PctMiss, it says there are no missing vals, but I know there are.

Comment: You are missing commas from your "merged" query.

Comment: Same comment as @Tim, you need commas after 'MISS_VAL', and 'PctMiss'